# What is policy π in offline RL constraint method?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

In Berkeley's cs285 deep RL course, in offline RL lecture, Levine says that there is a closed form solution to the constrained problem (in the picture below), but he doesn't explain what the policy π (over which the advantage is calculated) is. It takes `max` over π and π should not be present in the optimal solution. Can somebody help please me understand this?[image]

Comment: $pi$ is just the policy space (aka take the max over all possible policies that do not violate the constraint)